# Getting an error when trying to re-assign an @ObservedObject in a SwiftUI View "Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable"

Tags: swiftui

I'm getting an error when trying to **re-assign** an observed object from within the swift view

My code is along these lines:

```
struct MyApp: App {
  @State var dataSource: Datasource()
  @ObservedObject datastream = DataStream("defaultStream") // a placeholder that needs to be replaced
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        
        ContentView().onAppear {
           // I need to update this somehow...
           // Error is:
           // Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable
           self.datastream = dataSource.subscribe(stream: "someStream") 
        }
    }   
  }
}
```

the data code is like this:

```
class Datasource {

    ....
    var streams: [String:DataStream] = [:]
    func subscribe(streamName: String) -> DataStream {
       ....
       let newStream = DataStream(streamName)
       streams[streamName] = newStream
       return newStream
    }
}

class DataStream : ObservableObject {
     @Published var data : [DataEvents] = []
     ....
}
```

Comment: This is expected, you can change the properties within but not the reference object itself. BTW StateObject is for initializing and ObservedObject is for passing around

Comment: Try to learn the `View` struct for your updates, `body` is like data changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what @ObservedObject and @StateObject were designed for. It's unsafe to re-create inside the View lifecycle since View might be re-rendered over and over again at any time.

In this circumstance, I believe your purpose is to change `DataStream`. So I think you should create a single instance of DataStream when MyApp is initialized. Then, after updating its properties, it will automatically notify subviews that are listening and `dataStream` could be used later. Now you've got a single source of truth here (dataStreamManager) that holds modifiable data.

```swift
class DataStreamManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dataStream = DataStream("default")
}
```

```swift
struct MyApp: App {
    @State private var dataSource = Datasource()
    @StateObject private var dataStreamManager = DataStreamManager()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onAppear {
                    dataStreamManager.dataStream = dataSource.subscribe(streamName: "streamName")
                }
                //.environmentObject(...) <- might be injected here
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: I have no idea why you're using `@State var dataSource = Datasource()` here. You may want to take a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-user-interface-state). BTW, @State/@StateObject should always declare as private.